# Query not executing

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

```sql
select top(200) * 
FROM ._Click C with (nolock) 
INNER JOIN CLM_Sendlog S with (nolock) on S.TriggeredSendID = C.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID 
where C.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = '7e248b8b-5e73-ec11-a318-48df370ed850' 
and S.Subcategory in ('CONFIRM' , 'ORD_CONFIRM')
```

I am not able to execute the query. It is not showing any results, it's just handing up.

Comment: There's no point in using "with (nolock)" in SFMC.

Comment: And to @Ali's point, use of `select *` is not advisable as column names are cached in SFMC.

Answer (score 2):

You should delete the dot just before "_Click" and specify the exact column names while using JOINs instead of wildcard (*).